# Instagram API - Unable to request access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram-api, httparty

Using **HTTParty** I tried to request for the access token as below:

```
result = HTTParty.post("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
{ 
  :body => [ { "client_id" => xxxxxxxxxx, "client_secret" => xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
  "redirect_url" => 'http://localhost:4000/access_token', "code" => xxxxxxxx } ].to_json,
  :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
})
```

But the response says that **#400, "error_type"=>"OAuthException", "error_message"=>"You must provide a client_id"}, @response=#, @headers={"content-language"=>["en"], "expires"=>["Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"],........**

Can't figure out why.. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can change content-type into:

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

For more information click [instagram-api-authentication-must-provide-client-id](http://blog.humphriesj.com/2013/12/instagram-api-authentication-you-must.html)

I hope this help you.